# Neovim for windows not available on GitHub

Tags: windows, vim, neovim

[image]

I'm very new to vim. I just started today.

Neovim used to have 8 assets with 2 for windows called `nvim-win32` and `nvim-win64`. They are not there anymore. Does anyone know what happened or when they will be back for download? Or will I need to work with the source file?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: All 8 are in the latest tag: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.4.4

Answer (score 0):

The windows binaries are not included for every release. They are included in most of them, though, including the release tagged with "latest release".